# Twitter integration with Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to integrate twitter with my app in Android. I was trying out the androidHive guide given here in http://goo.gl/VF4Pk

I am getting the below error everytime I click on the login to twitter button.

```
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667): Process: com.example.testoauthtweets, PID: 30667
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:150)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.example.testoauthtweets.MainActivity.loginToTwitter(MainActivity.java:189)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.example.testoauthtweets.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:175)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.example.testoauthtweets.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:123)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-24 08:58:09.659: E/AndroidRuntime(30667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

I am getting the error here:

```
    private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) 
    {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    else 
    {
        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I updated the Library files to latest. Now I am able to get the login screen after I login and accept the access it gets back to my app but then it always shows **Login error - NULL**. Looks like the access token is not getting updated or accepted.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: which is 189th line? please tell me?

Comment: TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
   twitter = factory.getInstance();

Answer (score 0):

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

You are doing network related operation in UI(Main) thread. You must be doing that in a separate worker thread or use an asynctask for that.

[NetworkOnMainThreadException - Developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Note : This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher.

**UPDATE 1:** 
In your case put the code for fetching the request token and fetching authentication url in doInBackground method of asynctask.

Comment: I am not sure where I have to do the asynctask part?

Comment: wherever you are trying to call the twitter4j methods which in turn calls the api to fetch the data over internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out if it works:

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
// Check if already logged in
if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) 
{
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();

    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    twitter = factory.getInstance();

    try {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                         this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();



    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

else 
{
    // user already logged into twitter
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I updated the Library files to latest. Now I am able to get the login screen after I login and accept the access it gets back to my app but then it always shows Login error - NULL.

Comment: I am not getting anything except Login error - NULL

Comment: Try this bcz it worked for me i am integrating this in all my project. https://github.com/khetiyachintan/Android-Twitter-Example  .

Comment: I tried even that...It logged me in but then on posting I am getting Async error did you come across the same problem. Check this: http://txs.io/8bT

Comment: use twitter core lib version 3.0.6? have you used it?

Comment: I am using Twitter4j-core-4.0.1 because old one doesn't allow me to login too